# groovy/java check list intersections and combine elements

Tags: java, list, groovy, intersection

I have a list:

```
def a = [[14, 17, 12, 5], [14, 17, 12, 8, 3], [5, 2], [9]]
```

I need to check intersections and if two lists intersect, combine them.

The result should be as follows:

```
def b = [[14, 17, 12, 5, 8, 3, 2], [9]]
```

(i.e 14 is in first sublist, which is also in second sublist, and recursively so on...)
How this task can be solved?

Comment: I have tried to do two for loops, where second loop checks intersection with first loop sublist. Them to do flatten().unique(). But this was not correct solution (I think I made some mistakes during the implementation)

Comment: Why does 8 and 3 end up in the big list?

Comment: I need to combine lists if there are intersecting elements.

Comment: So any intersecting element in any list pulls the whole list in?

Comment: tim_yates: yes, pulles in the whole list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in Groovy:

```
def a = [[14, 17, 12, 5], [14, 17, 12, 8, 3], [5, 2], [9]]

def rslt = a.inject( [ ] ) { c, n ->
  for( cc in c ) {
    if( n.find { it in cc } != null ) {
      cc.addAll( n )
      cc = cc.unique()
      return c
    }
  }
  c << n
}

assert rslt == [[14, 17, 12, 5, 8, 3, 2], [9]]
```

Comment: Any reason why not `a.inject([]) { c, n -> ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example using some of Groovy's set "inspired" methods on lists

```
def a = [[14, 17, 12, 5], [14, 17, 12, 8, 3], [5, 2], [9]]

def res = a.inject([]){ acc,val ->
    def isect =  acc.find{ val.intersect(it)}?.with{ it.addAll(val - it) }
    !isect ? acc << val : acc
}

assert res.containsAll([[14, 17, 12, 5, 8, 3, 2], [9]])
```