# Merge sub arrays containing that have intersection in Groovy / Java

Tags: arrays, groovy

Suppose we have one array:

```
def a = [[0], [1], [2], [2, 1], [1, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3], 
        [4, 3], [3, 4], [4], [5], [6], [8], [10, 7], [7, 10], 
        [7, 8], [8, 7], [9], [10], [7, 10, 8], [8, 9], [9, 8], 
        [11, 0], [0, 11]]
```

then

`def b = reduce(a)`

should produce

```
[ [0, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6], [7,8,9,10] ]
```

My logic was to have a new array `reducedObjects` that would contain the result. First subarray from `objects` is copied to `reducedObjects` and then next subarray is checked if has intersection with subarrays from `reducedObjects`. If there is an intersection, then make a union from the subarray in `reducedObjects` and the original subarray.

```
def reduce(objects) {
    def reducedObjects = new ArrayList()
    objects.each { object ->
        if (reducedObjects.size() == 0) {
            reducedObjects << object
        } else {
            def isReduced = false
            for (int i = 0; i < reducedObjects.size(); i++) {

                def equals = false
                object.each { it ->
                    if(reducedObjects[i].contains(it)) {
                        equals = true
                        isReduced = true
                    }
                }
                if (equals) {
                    reducedObjects[i] = (object + reducedObjects[i]).unique().sort()
                    reducedObjects.unique()
                }

            }
            if(!isReduced) {
                reducedObjects << object
            }
        }
    }
    return reducedObjects.unique()
}
```

The following function do not work fine, as the result is:

```
[[0, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6], [7, 8, 9, 10], [8, 9]]
```

The problem is that `reducedObjects` has an subarray `[7, 8]` and then the next subarray is `[9]`.  The function will create a new subarray as there is no intersection, but in next iteration, there is a subarray [8, 9] and it is merged in both `[7,8]` and `[9]`.

Is there any better solution to do this? Or somehow to improve this solution?

Comment: What is your question? If you're simply going to ask how it is done (requesting the code), that is too broad. Show your effort so far and explain what the problem is.

Comment: also right now there appears to be no logic from `a` to `b` except `b` has unique numbers, but the subarrays don't have any context/explanation

Comment: @tnw I updated my answer. I need to merge all the subarrays that have intersection.

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do...  DO you have a simpler example?

Comment: @tim_yates ok, here is a simpler example:

`def a = [ [1, 2, 3], [3, 4], [5, 6] ]` should become `[ [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6] ]`. So  `[1,2,3]` and `[3,4]` should merge as they share same element `3`

Comment: Looks like [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I think the main problem you are having is because you are just considering the initial merge of input object with the reducedObjects item - but you need a further consolidation step to merge those merged items.

Comment: I edited the question to contain the code as other users wanted to see what was the problem. I do not force be done in this way - I need it done in any / best / way :) @rhinds

Comment: This feels very similar to this question from 2 years ago. http://stackoverflow.com/q/15816396/6509

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment above - I think the problem lies here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < reducedObjects.size(); i++) {

    def equals = false
    object.each { it ->
        if(reducedObjects[i].contains(it)) {
            equals = true
            isReduced = true
        }
    }
    if (equals) {
        reducedObjects[i] = (object + reducedObjects[i]).unique().sort()
        reducedObjects.unique()
    }

}
```

Here, you are iterating over your input list (current item from that list being `object`) and comparing that object with all the previously reduced lists and merging them, but for every reduced list it is being merged.

Imagine your `reducedObjects` looks like `[[7,8],[9,10]]` and object is `[8,9]` - then this code will merge `object` `[8,9]` with both those existing items.

A more idiomatic groovy approach might be something like:

```
def a = [[0], [1], [2], [2, 1], [1, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3],
    [4, 3], [3, 4], [4], [5], [6], [8], [10, 7], [7, 10],
    [7, 8], [8, 7], [9], [10], [7, 10, 8], [8, 9], [9, 8],
    [11, 0], [0, 11]]

def reduced = []

a.each{ incoming ->
    List allReducedLists = (reduced.findAll{ r ->  incoming.intersect(r) } + incoming).flatten().unique()
    reduced = reduced.findAll{ r -> !allReducedLists.intersect(r) } 
    reduced << allReducedLists
}

println reduced
```

(not tested beyond the above input, so maybe missed some cases)

Comment: +1 for this very elegant solution. I assume the complexity is O(n**2) which is not bad and probably not easy to top..

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option you have got that uses a recursive closure:

```
def a = [[0], [1], [2], [2, 1], [1, 2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3],
    [4, 3], [3, 4], [4], [5], [6], [8], [10, 7], [7, 10],
    [7, 8], [8, 7], [9], [10], [7, 10, 8], [8, 9], [9, 8],
    [11, 0], [0, 11]
]

def reducedList
reducedList = {l->
    def r = []
    def found = false
    l.each{a1->
        found = false
        l.each{a2->
            if(a1!=a2){
                if(a1.intersect(a2).size()>0){
                    r.push(a1.plus(a2).sort().unique())
                    found = true
                }
            }
        }
        if(found==false)r.push(a1.sort().unique())
    }
    return (r.unique()==l)?r.unique():reducedList(r)
} 
println reducedList(a) //[[0, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```